# Pattern matching for attributions in R

Tags: r

Is there any pattern matching approach for looping through a list of variables in R?

I'm quite aware of using indices, but, so far, I've found none on multiple attributions in a loop.

What I have is this:

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
y <- c(4, 3, 2, 1)
for (i in 1:length(x)) {
    x[i]
    y[i]
}
```

and I would like to have:

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
y <- c(4, 3, 2, 1)
for ((xi, yi) in c(x, y)) {
    xi
    yi
}
```

Regards!

Comment: `%in%`?  `grepl`?  Nested for loops?  Depending on what you're asking, one of those is the solution.

Comment: The `(x, y)` you mean is `(1, 4), (2, 3), (3, 2), (4, 1)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, R doesn't let you unpack values in this way. You can only assign each element in the sequence to a single variable.

See here:
http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#for

Comment: Yep, my intention was to unpack the value, like I'm able to do in python, or sml. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `mapply` instead of `for` loops:

E.g.,

```
mapply(c, x, y)
```

runs the function `c` with all values in `x` and  `y` at the same index, i.e., `x=1` and `y=4` etc.

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    3    4
[2,]    4    3    2    1
```

It is also possible to define new functions:

```
mapply(function(xi, yi) "your function", x, y)
```

Comment: I considered using mapply, but I've stumbled on some difficulties, since not all of my arguments are iterable, some of then I'd like to have fixed. My main will was to calculate the euclidean distance from a vector of points c(x, y) to a given point, say (0, 0), without using a for loop.

Comment: @Rubens Could you give an example?

Comment: I was trying to do this: dist <- function(x, y, a, b) {/*euclidean distance formula using x and y as coords for point A, and a and b representing point B*/}; so i'd have x <- c(1, 2, 3), y <- c(1, 2, 3), and my comparison point cx <- 0, cy <- 0. I would then: mapply(dist, x, y, cx, cy), but this simply doesnt' work as i expected

Comment: @Rubens This can easily be achieved with the built-in `dist` function: `stats::dist(rbind(c(cx, cy), cbind(x,y)))[seq_along(x)]` returns the three distances from the comparison point.

Comment: whoa, amazing! works like a charm! now i'll take some time to grasp the meaning of these col/row bind functions (: Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the foreach package:

> http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/index.html

I think you will find what you want with the foreach() function.